# post request not working in laravel livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

hello guys I'm new to laravel and livewire please kindly assist, post request not going through , if i click on the submit nothing is happening, I'm not getting error either, I have added the livewire script in my app.blade.php and it's rendering properly

Post Create form

```html
<div>
    <div class="p-4 mx-auto mt-3 bg-gray-100 md:p-8 md:w-4/5 md:mt-0">
        <h1 class="mb-3 text-xl font-semibold text-gray-600">New post</h1>
        <form wire:submit.prevent="createPost" action="#" class="px-4 py-6 space-y-4">
            <div class="overflow-hidden bg-white rounded-md shadow">
                <div class="px-4 py-3 space-y-8 sm:p-6">
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">
                        <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                            <input class="w-full" type="text"
                               wire:model="post.title" placeholder="Post title" />
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="flex flex-col">
                        <textarea id="body" rows="4" wire:model="post.body"
                           class="border-gray-300 rounded-sm form-textarea">
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="px-4 py-3 text-right bg-gray-50 sm:px-6">
                    <button type="submit" class="inline-flex justify-center">
                        post
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my post create livewire method

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Post;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class PostCreate extends Component
{
    public $post;
    public $points = 10;
    public $energy = 1;

    public function increment()
    {
        $this->points++;
    }

    protected $rules = [
        // 'category' => 'required|integer|exists:categories,id',
        'title' => 'required|min:4',
        'body' => 'required|min:4',
    ];

    public function createPost()
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            $this->validate();

            $post = Post::create([
                'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                // 'category_id' => $this->category,
                'body' => $this->body,
                'title' => $this->title,

            ]);


            $users = auth()->user();
            $users->increment('points', 10);

            session()->flash('success_message', 'Post was added successfully!');

            $this->reset();

            return redirect()->route('posts.index');
        }

        // abort(Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.post-create');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `wire:model` points to `post.title`, however, your validation is just for `title`. This is the same for `body`.

Comment: I have changed that but still not working

Comment: did you check if livewire assets were loaded?

Comment: yes sure I checked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two thing here to note - you don't initialize `$this->post` and you don't have the proper validation. You need to check for `post.title` and `post.body`, and you also need to display the actual errors.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Post;
use Livewire\Component;

class PostCreate extends Component
{
    public $post;
    public $points = 10;
    public $energy = 1;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->post = new Post;
        $this->post->user_id = auth()->id();
    }

    public function increment()
    {
        $this->points++;
    }

    protected $rules = [
        // 'category' => 'required|integer|exists:categories,id',
        'post.title' => 'required|min:4',
        'post.body' => 'required|min:4',
    ];

    public function createPost()
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            $this->validate();

            $post = $this->post->save();

            auth()
                ->user()
                ->increment('points', 10);

            session()->flash('success_message', 'Post was added successfully!');

            $this->reset();

            return redirect()->route('posts.index');
        }

        // abort(Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.post-create');
    }
}
```

To display the errors from validation, you can add the following snippet in your blade-file,

```html
@if ($errors->any())
    <ul>
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `lazy` to `the wire.model`:

```
<input class="w-full" type="text" ﻿wire:model.lazy="post.title" placeholder="Post title" />
```

```
<textarea id="body" rows="4" wire:model.lazy="post.body" ﻿class="border-gray-300 rounded-sm form-textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: Why would this suddenly make it work?